# unable to return a binary result from durable functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to use durable functions to return a binary result. Currently I have this setup:

```
[FunctionName("HelloOrchestration")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RunOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var input = context.GetInput<something>();

    var outputs = new List<Task<string>>();
    foreach (var group in input.packages)
    {
        outputs.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<string>("HelloOrchestration_Hello", group));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(outputs);
    
    // location of the result
    result = ...;

    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(result, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose));
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = Path.GetFileName(result),
    };
    result.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    return result;
}

[FunctionName("HelloOrchestration_Hello")]
public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] something input, ILogger log)
{
    return something.BuildSomething(input);
}

[FunctionName("HelloOrchestration_HttpStart")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    ILogger log)
{
    var input = ...;
    
    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("HelloOrchestration", null, input);
    
    log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

    var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(240);
    var retryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); // How often to check the orchestration instance for completion

    return await starter.WaitForCompletionOrCreateCheckStatusResponseAsync(req, instanceId, timeout, retryInterval);
}
```

It all seems to work fine except the return result. What I get back is:

```
{
    "Version": "1.1",
    "Content": {
        "Headers": [
            {
                "Key": "Content-Type",
                "Value": [
                    "application/octet-stream"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Key": "Content-Disposition",
                "Value": [
                    "attachment; filename=Genie.23.1-1823.zip"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ReasonPhrase": "OK",
    "Headers": [
        {
            "Key": "Cache-Control",
            "Value": [
                "no-cache"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "TrailingHeaders": [],
    "RequestMessage": null,
    "IsSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

but not an actual binary I want to return. Am I missing something? When I inspect result I do see that `result.Content` gets assigned correctly and I am using the same response via regular azure functions which works fine and return binary.

Answer (score 0):

You try this code. I try in my side and its working fine.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Bson;

namespace FunctionApp8
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            // Replace "hello" with the name of your Durable Activity Function.
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", "Tokyo"));
            //outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", "Seattle"));
            await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function2_Binary", "London");

            // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
            return outputs;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1_Hello")]
        public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Saying hello to {name}.");
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }

        [FunctionName("Function2_Binary")]
        public static void Returnbinary([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
        {
             
            string filepath1 = @"D:\stack Projects\FunctionApp8\data.json";
            byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath1);
            string jsonData1 = File.ReadAllText(filepath1);
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData1);
            JsonSerializer serializer1 = new JsonSerializer();
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            BsonWriter bson = new BsonWriter(memoryStream);

            Console.WriteLine("-------------------Orginal Data------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(jsonData1);
            Console.WriteLine();
            serializer1.Serialize(bson, obj);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------1st Data------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()));
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------2nd Data------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray()));

            Console.ReadKey();
  
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            // Function input comes from the request content.
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Function1", null);

            log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }
    }
}
```

Using your json to convert into binary.

```json
{
  "Version": "1.1",
  "Content": {
    "Headers": [
      {
        "Key": "Content-Type",
        "Value": [
          "application/octet-stream"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Key": "Content-Disposition",
        "Value": [
          "attachment; filename=Genie.23.1-1823.zip"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "ReasonPhrase": "OK",
  "Headers": [
    {
      "Key": "Cache-Control",
      "Value": [
        "no-cache"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "TrailingHeaders": [],
  "RequestMessage": null,
  "IsSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

Output
[image]

```
 -------------------Orginal Data------------------------------
{
  "Version": "1.1",
  "Content": {
    "Headers": [
      {
        "Key": "Content-Type",
        "Value": [
          "application/octet-stream"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Key": "Content-Disposition",
        "Value": [
          "attachment; filename=Genie.23.1-1823.zip"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "ReasonPhrase": "OK",
  "Headers": [
    {
      "Key": "Cache-Control",
      "Value": [
        "no-cache"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "TrailingHeaders": [],
  "RequestMessage": null,
  "IsSuccessStatusCode": true
}


{
  "Version": "1.1",
  "Content": {
    "Headers": [
      {
        "Key": "Content-Type",
        "Value": [
          "application/octet-stream"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Key": "Content-Disposition",
        "Value": [
          "attachment; filename=Genie.23.1-1823.zip"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "ReasonPhrase": "OK",
  "Headers": [
    {
      "Key": "Cache-Control",
      "Value": [
        "no-cache"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "TrailingHeaders": [],
  "RequestMessage": null,
  "IsSuccessStatusCode": true
}

-------------------1st Data------------------------------

Content-Type♦Value%☻0↓application/octet-stream♥1^☻Key¶Content-Disposition♦Value5☻0)attachment; filename=Genie.23.1-1823.zip↕StatusCode?☻ReasonPhrase♥OK♦Headers@♥08☻Key♫Cache-Control♦Value§☻0  no-cache♦TrailingHeaders♣
RequestMessagIsSuccessStatusCode☺
-------------------2nd Data------------------------------

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
```